# Keep selected items from selectbox after submit

Tags: jquery, forms, asp-classic

I have this code to check the checkboxes after submit:

```
function checkThis() {
    var f = document.MyFormName.MyFieldName;
    var s = "<% Response.Write MyFieldName %>";
    for (i=0; i<f.length; i++)
        if (s.indexOf(f[i].value)!=-1) {
            f[i].checked = true;
        }
}
window.onload = checkThis;
```

I would like to have the same thing for the `<select></select>`.

My selectbox is a multi-selectbox actually.

Comment: I just tried mix some `document.getElementById("mySelect").selectedIndex="X";` without luck

Comment: Post what you've tried.

Comment: Don't have the code anymore, so I grab something I have working for checkbox as a start up for the selectbox.

Answer (score 0):

The selectedIndex value is usefull only for single selection drop down lists.
Try this instead:

```
function selectThis() {
    var f = document.MyFormName.MySelectName;
    var s = "<% Response.Write MySelectName %>";
        for (i=0; i<f.length; i++)
        {
            f.options[i].selected = (s.indexOf(f.options[i].value)!=-1);
        }
}
```

See also this link for a brief explanation: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_select_options.asp